# Exception in struts taglib

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

I am trying to run login page but getting `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagExtraInfo class: org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.IterateTei`

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Fetch CAMS Data and Upload it to CM</title>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="/Login_Act">
<html:errors/>
<table width="500" align="center">
<caption>Login<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></caption>
<tr>
<td>
User Name :
</td>

<td>
<html:text property="userName" value=""/>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password :
</td>

<td>
<html:password property="pwd" value=""/>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<html:submit value="Login"/>

</td>

</tr>
</table>
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added `struts.jar` and `struts1.4.8.jar` in build path,still gettin the error.

Comment: Are these jars in your webapp's WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Do you also have jsp-api.2.0.jar in WEB-INF/lib? (You shouldn't have)

Comment: Thanks alot,it worked after removing jsp-api.2.0.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure struts.jar is in your webapp's classpath (add it to WEB-INF/lib if it's not there already)
- Make sure jsp-api.2.0.jar is NOT in WEB-INF/lib